# Wrong column type Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, ordinal

I have an enum and want to store it as integer in the database. I put the annotation *@Enumerated(value=EnumType.ORDINAL)* at my attribute and start my application with hibernate.validate. It then says the following:

```
Wrong column type in administation for column job. Found: int, expected: varchar(255)
```

Does anyone have a clue why it is like that?

**EDIT**

My enum looks like the following:

```
public enum JobEnum {
  private int value;
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private String className;
  private boolean unique;

  private JobEnum(int value, String name, String description, String className, boolean unique) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.className = className;
    this.unique = unique;
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

And of course it has the getters for the values.

My table is named administration and has the column job which is of the type integer and can be NULL.

Comment: Hibernate has two APIs. One is the JPA API, the other one is hibernate's own API. May this problem result out of a mixture of both?

Comment: Do you update the column type? You may need to drop the current job column from the table first so that Hibernate will regenerate the column with the correct data type

Comment: How can I check which API is used? I don't update the type. It is an integer in the database and it needs to be an integer. I don't generate it with hibernate.

Comment: Can you please provide us with the table structure and with the exact from the enum class and the entity class?